# How can I successfully uninstall the new Mac Pages program and go back to the 09 version

Tags: macos, pages, iwork

I'm currently working on a project that requires hyper links, which I was able to create in the 09 version of Pages, and which could be exported to PDF with all hyper links fully operational.

Unfortunately the new version of Pages won't do this (you can enter hyper links in but they won't work when exported to PDF).

I do have both the old version, as well as the new version of Pages on my mac. However every time I open up an existing file, or create a new one, in the 09 version, it automatically asks me if I want to upgrade this to the new version. To not upgrade one needs to click "edit existing copy." But the problem is when you save it (which has to aways be as a copy) and then close the file, it seems to save it regardless in the new version, or certainly when re-opening this same file, all the hyper links and other goodies associated with the 09 version, are all gone.

As far as I'm concerned the 09 version is a way superior product. Therefore I figured the best way to go is to completely get rid of the new version and go back to the old one.

Is this possible, and if so how can I go about doing this in a way that won't affect any of my files? I have them all backed up anyway, but just wanted to make sure before going this way and want to make sure I can go back to the 09 version without any major issues.

My 09 version was originally loaded in via disk by the way. Please advise if possible, thanks guys.

Comment: In my latest Pages.app v5.1 Hyperlinks do work in PDFs.

It is possible that is the Application you are opening them in that does not recognise the links. I used Preview.app. I do not have (want) Adobe Reader on my mac.

Answer (score 3):

The Mac App Store updates to iWork should not have replaced the original iWork '09 apps. Simply delete the new apps and use the old ones.

The original apps should still be available under **/Applications/iWork '09** as well as if you search for them in Spotlight. If you've deleted the older versions, you can use Time Machine or reinstall them from the retail CD.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to. I tried just deleting the new one and a couple weeks later, it says you need to update. There was no other way of opening the file besides opening. And also, some of my files wouldn't open for school!!! PLEASE FIND A WAY TO DO THIS.

Comment: Hi welcome to AskDifferent, I find if a question is worth answering it is worth upvoting.  Also some instructions and a link may get you more upvotes. Please take the time to read the Answer and Question section of the [help](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help) page. As you can also see the question has been answered and there is a way to do what was requested in the question.